# Neural Network Classification with several input of different type

Tags: input, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, normalization

I've started to study neural networks and now I'm learning to use them to classify objects.

But I have 1 doubts:

How should I represent the input array if the inputs have **different type** (e.g. number and string)?

For example if i have to classify an apartment (array with the same type (all int)), I can consider the number of bedrooms, bathrooms etc, so I will have an array like this:

> [2,2,1] = [2 bathrooms, 2 bedrooms, 1 living room]

Then I will normalize the value in a range between 0 and 1 like this:

> [1,1,0.5]

Is that right?

**But** what if I have to classify a group of people according their age and nationality (**a number and a string**)?

The first idea could be to to assign different nationality to a specific value between 0 and 1 but could this solution affect the classification? Because the nationality with value 1 could affect more the result than a nationality with value 0,1.

Is that stupid to assume? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The nationality is a categorical input. Instead of assigning a value between 0 and 1, you assign a one-hot-encoding vector. For instance, if you have 3 nationalities (US, China and France), you can do the following: US: `[1, 0, 0]`, China: `[0, 1, 0]` and France: `[0, 0, 1]`

Comment: You can also see what is called "embedding".

Comment: @vinzee Thanks for your help! So just to be sure I have fully understood let's say that I want to set as input a 22 years old American I will use the array [0.22, 1, 0, 0]? The 0.22 is the normalized age.

Comment: Yes, I think that would work.